# Handling an AngularJS popup with Selenium WD

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium-webdriver

The following picture shows a pop-up that appears when clicked on the "Random User" text; WD is not able to shift its focus to the pop-up you see.

[image: Please check the picture here]

Below is the code I employed with various trial codes commented as in

```
public static void teardownAppRetrieveOnce() throws InterruptedException {
    synchronized(obj){
        obj.wait(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sidebar']/nav/ul[2]/li[3]/button[1]/span/span")).click();
        System.out.println("Clicked sidebar..");
        obj.wait(2000);
        String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();
        **driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);
        driver.switchTo().findElement(By.id(".//*[@id='logoutButton']")).click();**
        ***driver.switchTo().activeElement().findElement(By.id(".//*[@id='logoutButton']")).click();***
        System.out.println("Clicked on logout");
        obj.wait(2000);
        driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
        obj.wait(2000);
        System.out.println("Logged out...");
    }
}
```

Please help me clarify if such pop-up means a separate new window or frame that is to be handled?

NOTE:

- ** means the first solution I tried that failed
- *** means the second solution i tried that too failed

Comment: Hi, good to have HTML code to know what it is

Comment: any website where this type of pop-up available so that we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a lot of trouble with WebDriver/AngularJS. Sometimes native Selenium methods of `WebElement`s work - sometimes not. The best solution is to execute raw Javascript on the web page.

I your case, it would be something like this:

```
driver.executeScript("$x(\".//*[@id='logoutButton']\")[0].click()");
```